# Функция script и css, установка значения по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Подскажите, есть вот такой код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide(id) {var o=document.getElementById(id).style; o.display=o.display?'': 'none'}
    </script>
```

При клике он выравнивает display на none и при втором клике display на 0
Но нужно, что бы он по умолчанию display выравнивал на none.
И что бы если элемент потерял фокус, значение снова сбрасывалось на none

PS: Если я ставлю display в CSS таблице по умолчанию на none, скрипт не выполняет никаких действий.

Comment: display из css в e.style не отображается.                
 `o.display=o.display?'none': '';` - перепутали

Comment: Не работает(( форма вообще просто грузиться и не производит не каких действий

Comment: Всё, понял, перечитал, осознал)))

Comment: Как мне теперь сделать что бы при клике за форму она пропадала ?

Comment: Проще сказать .focusout()

Comment: Переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос и приведите пример html-кода в редакторе. Из ваших слов совершенно не понятно какое `выравнивание` вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие потери фокуса - blur. прячьте по умолчанию в css и будет работать

```
function hide(id) {
    var o=document.getElementById(id).style; o.display = o.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
document.getElementById('element_id').addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    e.target.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: а для чего здесь функция `hide`?

Comment: @webDev_, ее поправил просто, ее при клике и повторном клике вызывает, я не понял логику, просто поправил